# Dynamic dropdown returns a null from jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have written a dropdown list which is populated by the database. This is my dropdown code in JSP file.

```
 <td>Category:</td>
 <%
  try {
      dbConnect dbConnect = new dbConnect();
      Connection currentCon = dbConnect.Connect();
      System.out.println("Connection sucess");
      String sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
      PreparedStatement ps = currentCon.prepareStatement(sql);
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();%>
 <td><select name="category" class="form-control" required>
      <%
        while (rs.next()) {
           String cname = rs.getString("category_name");
           String id = rs.getString("category_id");
           System.out.println(id);
      %>
      <option value="<%= id%>"><%= cname%></option>
      <%
        }
      %>
      </select>
      <%
      } catch (SQLException sqe) {
            out.println(sqe);
      }
 %>
 </td>
```

The relevant servlet code is;

```
String id = request.getParameter("category");
```

In the sout of the dropdown in JSP it prints all the IDs in the category. But when it comes to the servlet it returns a null. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks like the id and cname are outside the scope of <% %>. Can you try declare them in parent scope ?

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any `<form> tag` neither `submit` button in your code ,try below code :

```
    <td>Category:</td>
     <form method="post"  action="yourservleturl">//form tag for submitting data

         <%
          try {
              dbConnect dbConnect = new dbConnect();
              Connection currentCon = dbConnect.Connect();
              System.out.println("Connection sucess");
              String sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
              PreparedStatement ps = currentCon.prepareStatement(sql);
              ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();%>
         <td><select name="category" class="form-control" required>
              <%
                while (rs.next()) {

              %>
              <option value="<%=rs.getString("category_id")%>"><%=rs.getString("category_name")%></option> // printing option values
              <%
                }
              %>
              </select>
              <%
              } catch (SQLException sqe) {
                    out.println(sqe);
              }
         %>
     <input type="submit" value="submit">///submit btn
  </form>
</td>
```

also get, dropdown value by `String id = request.getParameter("category");` .it should worked .

Answer (score 0):

The local variable should be sound out of while loop, because you need that value after while loop.

```
<%
try {
  dbConnect dbConnect = new dbConnect();
  Connection currentCon = dbConnect.Connect();
  System.out.println("Connection sucess");
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
  PreparedStatement ps = currentCon.prepareStatement(sql);
  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();%>
  String cname = null;
  String id = null;
 <td><select name="category" class="form-control" required>
  <%
    while (rs.next()) {
       cname = rs.getString("category_name");
       id = rs.getString("category_id");
       System.out.println(id);
  %>
```

Besides, I suggest you use Expression Language instead of `<%= id%>`

change
`<option value="<%= id%>"><%= cname%></option>`
to

`<option value="${id}">${name}</option>`

And don't forget submit button.

Comment: Still returns a null value

Comment: @NethminiRomina , can you get the drop box with categories in your database?